# Access violation. when using GLEW and GLFW

Tags: c++, opengl, glew, glfw

I am sure that everything is linked correcly. I initially was using glload and glfw from the Unofficial GLSDK but then I decided to do away with glload which meant that I had to use glew in order to get at the modern headers.

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>
```

I have included glew before glfw as per the instructions.

During run time the OpenGL window opens

```
//(relevant code)
if(!glewInit()) {return -1; }
if(!glfwInit()) {return -1; }
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
// also tried glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE);

if(!glfwOpenWindow(1024, 768, 8, 8, 8, 8, 24, 8, GLFW_WINDOW)){
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

glfwSetWindowTitle("OpenGL 3.2");

//init method
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);  //<<  Access violation here.
```

Any ideas what my problem is here?

I have looked at. "Access violation using VBO with glew" But it was no help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`glewInit` is to be called *after* a OpenGL context has been created and bound to the current thread, i.e. after `glfwOpenWindow` in your case.

Comment: Thank you I moved that like you said. if(!glewInit()) {return -1; } was incorrect to I need to check the value it returns. as its not a bool

Answer (score 3):

A little late, but figured I'd pipe in anyways.

As mentioned by datenwolf, in your relevant code posted the `glewInit()` should return an error due to it's positioning.

The other potential issue you could be encountering is described on http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library under the **GLEW** section.

copy-paste from above:

> GLEW has a problem with core contexts. 
>   It calls `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)`​, 
>   which causes `GL_INVALID_ENUM`​ on GL 3.2+ core context as soon as `glewInit()`​ is called.

Solution for GLEW (also provided by above link) is to enable 'EXPERIMENTAL' support. Ex:

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
GLenum err = glewInit();
if( err != GLEW_OK )
{
    printf("GlewInit error");
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also late but for anyone still looking

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
```

Before initializing the context was got rid of the access violation error, but instead made the program exit with a GL_INVALID_ENUM error. With GLFW, I had to additionally comment out the window hints:

```
//glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
//glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
//glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
//glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE);
```

The programs then started compiling!